# Is journald replacing or adding to syslogd

Tags: linux, logging, syslog, systemd-journald

My `/var/log/syslog` is containing, that's at least my feeling, the same data as journalctl shows.

Is there anything that is solely logged in one of both and is it advisable to remove one of them then in order to safe some space?

Comment: I think this is a great question, but it isn't related to programming and is therefore probably much better off on a different SE like [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) - which already has a somewhat similar question [Is rsyslog redundant on when using journald?](https://serverfault.com/questions/959982/is-rsyslog-redundant-on-when-using-journald)